# into_iter() available on Iterator and multiple times

Tags: rust, iterator, traits

I am new to rust and was going over iterators and this where I got blocked.So if I am implementing Iterator directly and not IntoIterator,how come I am able to call into_iter
(and too multiple times).My understanding is if I implemented IntoIterator,I should be going to Iterator via into_iter.But if I am able to implement Iterator,why do I still need into_iter(would be called implicitly if i didnt give I guess for for in )

```
struct StrSplit<'a> {
    rest: &'a str,
    delim: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> StrSplit<'a> {
    fn new(haystack: &'a str, delim: &'a str) -> Self {
        Self {
            rest: haystack,
            delim,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for StrSplit<'a> {
    type Item = &'a str;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let to_return;
        if let Some(next) = self.rest.find(self.delim) {
            to_return = &self.rest[..next];
            self.rest = &self.rest[next + self.delim.len() + 1..];
            return Some(to_return);
        } else if !self.rest.is_empty() {
            to_return = self.rest;
            self.rest="";
            return Some(to_return);
        }
        return None;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let check = StrSplit::new("this was to check what was to be checked", "was");

    let iterr = check.into_iter().into_iter().into_iter();
    for part in iterr {
        println!("{}", part);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're new to Rust this might be a bit subtle, but it's a thing that you'll see quite often with the traits of the standard library:

You correctly note that `into_iter` is a method of the `IntoIterator` trait. You also note that you implemented `Iterator` for your struct, but *not* `IntoIterator`. So what gives?

Checking the methods defined on `Iterator`, there's no `into_iter` to be found.

But now if you check the documentation for `IntoIterator`, and scroll down to the list of *Implementors* https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#implementors

you will find the following snippet:

```rust
impl<I> IntoIterator for I
where
    I: Iterator
```

This is called a *blanket implementation*: For any type `T` that implements the `Iterator` trait, there will be automatically an implementation for the `IntoIterator` trait!

Because your struct implements `Iterator`, it also gets `IntoIterator` implemented.

There's some other examples of this in the standard library. For example, if you implement `From<A>` for some type `B`, you automatically get the `Into<B>` trait implemented for type `A`.

Another example is `ToString`:

```rust
impl<T> ToString for T where
    T: Display + ?Sized,
```

Any type that implements the `Display` trait gets the `ToString` trait for free!

Comment: this helps a lot @Lagerbaer  .Now I get why I can write multiple into_iter. Ill look into blanket implementations.Any mental model to help with the reasoning behind such implementation in case of iterator?

Comment: Well the idea is that if something _is_ an iterator, it is trivial to turn it _into_ an iterator. And actually the source code for the implementation of `IntoIter` for `Iterator` just returns the iterator itself...